# Get The Parent Controller from a PartialView Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, child-actions

I have a **_Partial.cshtml** view which is called in a **Parent.cshtml** view in the following manner:

Parent.cshtml:

**@Html.Render("_Partial");**

In the **_Partial.cshtml** view, there is a button which is linked to a form in the following manner:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "DetailsController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

In the **DetailsController** I have the **Send** action which looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult Send(int orderId)
    {
        if (some condition)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(parentAction, parentController, new {orderId});
        }

      return RedirectToAction(action, controller, new {orderId});
    }
```

The issue I am having is that the **ParentActionViewContext** is null.

**How can I obtain the Parent Controller name of the partial view?**

Comment: What do you mean by "parent controller"? Controller used for previous request?

Comment: Yes. I would like to have the Controller that called the Parent.cshtml which in turn calls the _Partial.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is used for Parent/Child actions... not view partials. The only time this is not null is when you are in a child action.